# round corner controller is not working in adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool, corners

I am using a pen tool to draw a curve and I have made some sharp corners so that I can round it with a round controller.

But only at some point, it shows a round controller and most of the point is left out.

[image]

as you can see only 4 sharp corners have the controller even though a lot of other corners is also sharp.

What is the problem in adobe illustrator?

Comment: I can't replicate this problem. Perhaps you have two anchor points very close together, or the corners without rounding widget are bezier points with very short handles?

Comment: take the pen tool and draw `>` and tell me if you could found the corner.

Comment: Yep, I just did that and it works: `>` and corners are shown.

Answer (score 0):

A guess: You have set in the preferences ON option "hide the corner widget if the angle is greater than..."

Answer (score 0):

That tool doesn't like small shapes or tight corners! You can try to select the corners individually with the Direct Selection tool :A key: and see if they round then. Or making the shape larger way also work.